# Charts: How to set colors of left and right axis labels in LineChartView?

Tags: ios, swift, linechart, ios-charts

My graph is using custom `IAxisValueFormatters` to set the left and right axis labels (below).  I've tried using the `labelTextColor` properties on left and right axis (below) but they're not changing the label's font color.

```
class myViewController {

    func initalizeGraph() {

        //omitted for brevity

        let leftYAxisValueFormatter = SpeedAndHRLeftYAxisValueFormatter(measurementSystem: measurementSystem)
        lineChartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = iPhoneThemeColor1
        lineChartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = leftYAxisValueFormatter

        let rightYAxisValueFormatter = SpeedAndHRRightYAxisValueFormatter()
        lineChartView.rightAxis.labelTextColor = iPhoneThemeColor2
        lineChartView.rightAxis.valueFormatter = rightYAxisValueFormatter
    }
}

class SpeedAndHRLeftYAxisValueFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter {
    //left side is speed

    //multiplu value x 40 (.5 * x = 20?)
    var measurementSystem: MeasurementSystem

    init(measurementSystem: MeasurementSystem) {
        self.measurementSystem = measurementSystem
    }

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {

        let intValue = Int(value * 40)
        var suffixString = ""

        switch measurementSystem {
        case .US:
            suffixString =  "mph"
        case .Metric:
            suffixString = "km/h"
        }

        return "\(intValue)" + " " + suffixString
    }
}

class SpeedAndHRRightYAxisValueFormatter: IAxisValueFormatter {
    //right side is HR

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {

        let intValue = Int(value * 210)

        return "\(intValue)" + " " + "bpm"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add following code in `viewDidLoad()` method. This is working perfactly for me in one of my project.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    let leftYAxisValueFormatter = SpeedAndHRLeftYAxisValueFormatter(measurementSystem: measurementSystem)
    lineChartView.leftAxis.valueFormatter = leftYAxisValueFormatter
    lineChartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = iPhoneThemeColor1

    let rightYAxisValueFormatter = SpeedAndHRRightYAxisValueFormatter()
    lineChartView.rightAxis.valueFormatter = rightYAxisValueFormatter
    lineChartView.rightAxis.labelTextColor = iPhoneThemeColor2
}
```

Also, update you code for class create as follow:

```
@objc(LineChartFormatter)
class SpeedAndHRRightYAxisValueFormatter:NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
    ....
    //Your Code
    ....
}

@objc(LineChartFormatter)
class SpeedAndHRLeftYAxisValueFormatter:NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
    ....
    //Your Code
    ....
}
```

I hope this will help you.

[image: Line chart font colour change]

Comment: Thank you but no, this doesn't change anything.  I think the difference is that I am subclassing `IAxisValueFormatter` to customize the Y axis labels.

Comment: I'm also doing same thing what are you doing, but it's working for me.

Comment: Thank you but this is still not changing the color of the left axis and I actually crash on `let rightYAxisValueFormatter = SpeedAndHRRightYAxisValueFormatter()` in VDL for some reason 

Comment: Keep debug point and check all values in console, make sure that shouldn't be nil.

Comment: turns out I was setting my `leftAxis.labelTextColor` to white later in my code and forgot about it 